# Why is Python leaving non-existent files in my package?

Tags: python, pip

For whatever reason, when I install my package `pie` with `pip install --break-system-packages --user git+https://github.com/zurgeg/pie.git@ed00801`, it fails due to a mysterious phantom file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jg/.local/bin/pie", line 5, in <module>
    from pie.pie import cli
  File "/home/jg/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pie/pie.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .crusts.notdate.play.playdate_pie import playdate as crust_playdate
  File "/home/jg/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pie/crusts/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    globals()[submodule] = _import_module("." + submodule, __name__)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jg/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pie/crusts/notdate/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    if not submodule.startswith("_"):
```

Now, this file did exist at one point:

```bash
git -P log --all --full-history --no-color -- src/pie/crusts/notdate/__init__.py |
awk 'match($0, /commit/){ print substr($0, RSTART + 7, 7) }'
aaef1b9
33210c5
bd3ded3
```

That is, until I realized that the file was in the wrong place and moved it to its current position:

```bash
git diff aaef1b9 aaef1b9~1
diff --git a/src/pie/crusts/__init__.py b/src/pie/crusts/notdate/__init__.py
similarity index 58%
rename from src/pie/crusts/__init__.py
rename to src/pie/crusts/notdate/__init__.py
[...]
```

Deleting the file didn't do anything, Python still thinks it's there, and clearly it is, even after a `pip uninstall pie`. Now, I can just `rm` the file, but that's a temporary solution, because if I recreate it in the repository, install, and then delete it, the file is kept. Bumping the version to `0.2.2` doesn't work either.

I expect the file to just be deleted when I reinstall my package, but for whatever reason, it seems like `pip` isn't tracking that file as part of the package?

UPDATE: It still seems to be failing with all of these commands using both a venv and the system install:

- `pip install --no-cache-dir`
- `pip install --force`
- `pip install --force --no-cache-dir`

Comment: I went back to the branch or commit where the file was not, use git status to check if the file is appearing. Then generate the local package, perform a test. If everything is correct, perform a push. From your package tag, just delete it via github, if you committed directly to the main branch, just re-commit it so it doesn't persist.

Comment: Quick question: why are you install packages globally, _with `break-system-packages` specified_, instead installing them nicely safe and local in your project's virtual environment, as that is the only thing that _needs_ those packages?

Comment: Because for whatever reason, pipx hangs while trying to install it. That's a problem for later though.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. pipx now let's me install it properly but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: Remove your `build` directory from your package directory**

I decided to make a dummy file that would raise an exception for debugging purposes:

```bash
# Create a directory to put temporary debugging files
# Pie loads everything under "crusts" automatically
mkdir src/pie/crusts/temp
echo "raise Exception" > src/pie/crusts/temp/__init__py
```

Then, I uninstalled the package everywhere:

```bash
pip uninstall --break-system-packages pie
pipx uninstall pie
```

From there, I made a clean venv:

```bash
virtualenv ~/.venv
```

Lastly, I installed `pie` in the venv, and checked it, and it failed, so I uninstalled it...

```bash
# (from the venv)
pip install ./pie
pie
# traceback
Exception
pip uninstall pie
```

Lastly, I decided to see where the file remained, even with everything related to Pie uninstalled:

```bash
echo **/temp/__init__.py
pie/build/lib/pie/crusts/temp/__init__.py
```

I then just deleted the `build` directory:

```bash
rm -rf pie/build
```

And then bam, it works!

```bash
pie
[INFO] pie: Loading crusts...
# ...
```